# Format date in template to display in GMT time zone

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I'm using Kendo UI and in the template, I'm displaying the date

`#= kendo.toString(meetingDate, 'M/d/yyyy') #`

However, the date is stored and delivered in UTC time, but Kendo is automatically converting the date to my local time zone.  I want to get the time back in GMT and display the date.

The issue is that the time shift causes the date to display as the day before.

Edit:

This my current...hideous working solution

`#= kendo.toString(new Date(meetingDate.getUTCFullYear(), meetingDate.getUTCMonth(), meetingDate.getUTCDate()), 'M/d/yyyy') #`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging a little deeper, I found the timezone apply method built into kendo

`#= kendo.toString(kendo.timezone.apply(meetingDate, 'Etc/UTC'), 'M/d/yyyy') #`

This removes the need to add another library

Answer (score 1):

Use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/):

```
#= moment(meetingDate).utc().format('M/D/YYYY') #
```

You can also show the time in any [timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/).